# Short form of thank God

Tags: grammar, abbreviations

I know it's wrong to say thanks God, but since there is no abbreviation for thank, is it correct to say Tnx God?  I mean could 'Tnx God' be a short form of 'thank God'?

Comment: @Josh61 thx is short for thanks.  The whole question is about if it can also be short for thank.

Comment: Christopher Hitchens and Richard Dawkins are religious fanatics compared to me, but surely God, if one is going to thank her, deserves all 5 letters of the word.

Comment: The only widely recognized abbreviated form of "thank God" that I'm aware of in U.S. English entails thanking God for its being a particular day of the week: TGIF = "Thank God It's Friday"—which severely limits the breadth of your options for extreme-short-form gratitude.

Answer (score 3):

The use of a three letter abbreviation for "thanks" is a relatively new phenomenon that has experienced a recent uptick in usage in the age of texting, etc. As such, its use is inherently informal, and the rules surrounding its use are inherently in flux.

You are correct that "tnx God" (or the version I've seen more commonly, "thx God") would literally be expanded to "thanks God" which is not considered correct. "Thank God" is the expression you are looking for, and of course adding punctuation makes another valid expression: "Thanks, God!"

Since the use of this abbreviation is inherently informal, consider your audience. If they would understand your meaning to be "thank God" then go ahead and use it. Language is about effective communication. But understand that using it in this way is inherently ambiguous, and some people will most likely read it as "thanks God."

I know of no abbreviation for "thank" that is universally understood, but perhaps you could use "tk" or "thk" and hope your audience catches on. After all, that is how the abbreviation for "thanks" started in the first place.

Comment: I would say that "thx" for thanks has been around since the 70s, at least -- not an invention of the smartphone era.  Fairly rare, though.

Comment: @HotLicks fair point. I've edited to clarify my meaning, which is that it has enjoyed a recent uptick related to texting. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @Nonnal So, you mean we can make up an abbreviation just because "After all, that is how the abbreviation for "thanks" started in the first place".

Comment: @haha We can make up abbreviations, words, and sentences.  That's how English started in the first place.  The trick is getting others to understand you.

Comment: @CandiedOrange And what will happen if you make up a new word and I for myself. I don't think it would be a good idea unless some linguists and grammarian approve.

Comment: @haha linguists and grammarians do not approve words.  They read books and newspapers, etc, learn words already in use, then they document them in dictionaries.  As a English speaker I have as much authority to invent new words as Merriam-Webster does.  Actually more since Merriam-Webster's job is not to introduce new words.  It would be inappropriate for them to do so.  Stephen Colbert gave us [truthiness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truthiness) as a joke and now it's a word.

Comment: I favor regular usage and rules for formal writing to maximize communication effectiveness, but English is a productive language and informal use of novel words, abbreviations, constructions, etc is not inherently offensive. I'm a stickler for grammar and proper spelling, but I also use various abbreviations with family and friends that only they would understand because it's effective for communication with them. Grammarians don't dictate language. Language is inherently a bottom-up development. Linguists just document what is generally acceptable.

Comment: @CandiedOrange OK, I agree to some extent. But don't you think there should be a limit to that because the thought of inventing and saying whatever I want makes me shudder.

Comment: @haha there is absolutely a limit, but it's imposed automatically based on societal norms. Words and constructions that don't follow the rules are considered "wrong" until broadly adopted, at which point what used to be wrong is now acceptable. Consider the use of "who" in the objective case or "their" as a singular. If the new development is sufficiently useful, it will thrive. Otherwise it will die and remain "wrong."

Comment: @haha every word you just used was invented by somebody at some time.  The limit is popularity.  If I use an unpopular word I have to take responsibility for that by making my meaning clear.  I happen to be a Computer Scientist.  I live in a sea of made up jargon that I have to sift through.  So I know the pain.  But some ideas are new ideas and need new words.  And sometimes new words are just fun.  But it's your vocabulary.  Do what you will.

Comment: @Nonnal as you said *"After all, that is how the abbreviation for "thanks" started in the first place."* , so OP can simply say ***"Thanks God"*** or ***"Tnx God"*** , why bothers to ask if it is OK or not.

Comment: @haha I interpreted the original question as "Is this generally understood?" For more established words, there is a more definitive answer. I was trying to further explain that, since this context is inherently informal, the OP has more latitude than usual.